# Is there any way to replace the desktop dock app on the Droid 3? Or at least change the widgets/dock area icons in productivity mode?

Tags: docking-station, motorola-droid-3

I have the Motorola desktop dock for my Droid 3 (on Verizon). When I drop the Droid in the desktop dock it lets me bring up either nighttime mode or productivity mode. I'd like to change what happens in productivity mode. I don't need two calendar views, for instance, and I'd like to have the Gmail app on the right side, instead of messages, and I'd like music instead of the camera app.

Does anyone know how any of this can be modified? I'm happy to spend a few dollars on an app if it will be able to take over from the built-in one when I put the phone on the dock.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a replacement app, you could utilize [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) for that:

- Condition: Docked
- Task: Start App [your-replacement-app-here]

On the next docking, you would be asked for the app to perform this action with. Decide for "Tasker" and see if it works as expected. If it does, make it the default next time.

As alternate app you could e.g. use [Desk Clock Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DevBob.DeskClockPlus), which might even support this without the help of *Tasker*.